# Draw canvas on PreviewView

Tags: android, android-camerax

I am using the new `camerax` library to show camera preview using `PreviewView` component. I have a `canvas` object and I want to show it on the camera preview. how can I do that?

Here is the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraint_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
            android:id="@+id/view_finder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

I tried to use `draw` method on viewFinder but it did not work

```
val canvas = Canvas()

paint.apply {
    color = Color.RED
    textSize = 80.0f
    strokeWidth = 8.0f
}

canvas.drawLine(0f,0f,50f,50f,paint)
binding.viewFinder.draw(canvas)
```

There is a way to draw canvas on camera preview but it works only for `SurfaceView` not `PreviewView`.

```
surfaceHolder = surfaceView!!.holder
val canvas: Canvas = surfaceHolder!!.lockCanvas()

paint.apply {
    color = Color.RED
    textSize = 80.0f
    strokeWidth = 8.0f
}

canvas.drawLine(0f,0f,50f,50f,paint)
surfaceHolder!!.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas)
```

The problem is `SurfaceView` works only with `camera2` library, and I cannot use it with `camerax`. If the solution is to use `SurfaceView`, how can I do that with `camerax`?